# How can I remove the asterisk for required fields programatically?

Tags: theming, 8

How can I remove the asterisk Drupal inserts for required fields programatically (not hiding with CSS)?

In Drupal 7, there was [theme_form_required_marker()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_form_required_marker/7), but that's gone from Drupal 8.

Comment: "This question was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.". Just saying... Have you tried anything before asking?

Comment: The asterisk in D8 is added via css so it is just a matter of simply overriding the rule.

Comment: @IvanJaros If it matters, I'm using a Bootstrap subtheme, but in my markup I see the following: `<span class="form-required">*</span>`... it's not just CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be removed from the theme.  I'm using a Bootstrap subtheme, so in my case I copied `form-element-label-html.twig` from the bootstrap **templates** directory into my subtheme's **templates** directory, then changed the following line:

```
  {%- if required -%}
    <span class="form-required">*</span>
  {%- endif -%}
```

To:

```
  {%- if required -%}
    {# <span class="form-required">*</span> #}
  {%- endif -%}
```

Clear caches and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

**IMPORTANT**
Considering that '*' came on placeholder attribute, follows...

First, check if your contact form has a placeholder with '*', cause is lot easier if you can just remove it.

If you really need remove on code, you can do this via preprocess functions.

**THEME.theme**

```
function THEME_preprocess_input(&$variables) {
  //Alter the placeholder for inputs
  $variables['attributes']['placeholder'] = $variables['element']['#title'];
}

function THEME_preprocess_textarea(&$variables) {
  //Alter the placeholder for textarea
  $variables['attributes']['placeholder'] = $variables['element']['#title'];
}
```